# Apache Beam Combine.perKey using a compound key

Tags: java, apache-beam

I want to combine Measurements by type and device name.

```
public class Measurement implements Serializable {
    private String measurementType;
    private String device;
    private Long ts;
    private Double reading;
}
```

I am doing an average with `Combine.perKey(...)` successfully by the type. But I want to have basically a compound key of device and measurementType.

Right now my KvDoFn looks like this:

```
public class KvByMeasurementType extends DoFn<Measurement, KV<String, Measurement>> implements Serializable {
@DoFn.ProcessElement
    public void processElement(DoFn<Measurement, KV<String, Measurement>>.ProcessContext context) {
        Measurement measurement = context.element();
        context.output(KV.of(measurement.getMeasurementType(), measurement));
    }
}
```

How to extend it to create a compound key of two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a new object and make that the key. For example,

```
public class MyKey implements Serializable {
    private String measurementType;
    private String device;
}
```

And then generate and output `KV`s of type `MyKey` from your `KvByMeasurementType`.

Also, define a Beam [CombineFn](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.CombineFn.html) that performs the combining based on this key. See [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) for more information on the Beam's `Combine` transform.